# bot event has stopped all my commands from working

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

this is the code which is stopping all my bot commands:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    phrases = open("D:/code/code/DIscord bot/myFile.txt").readlines()
    phrases = list(map(lambda item: item.strip(), phrases))
    if message.content in phrases:
        msg = 'REAL!'
        await message.reply(msg)
```

i think its in the line

```
phrases = list(map(lambda item: item.strip(), phrases))
```

which is stopping the bot. This part of the code basically just has a text file of phrases and when one of those phrases is said, the bot will then reply with "REAL!". However, when trying to fix how the bot searches the list i think its messed up the code... please help.

and im also wondering how i can make the bot find these phrases in sentences, for example:
find "i love coding" in "man i gotta say i love coding"
but i mainly just want my code to work.

This part of the code basically just has a text file of phrases and when one of those phrases is said, the bot will then reply with "REAL!". However, when trying to fix how the bot searches the list i think its messed up the code... please help.

Comment: There is nothing in that line that will block.  It has to be awaiting the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [discord.py FAQ](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working):
You need to change your `@client.event` to `@client.listen('on_message')` and that should fix your issue